# running Karma in grunt with IE launcher in Linux box

Tags: linux, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, karma-jasmine

We're creating a Linux build box for an angular and node application, we have setup grunt to run unit tests against 3 browsers (IE, Chrome and FF).
 Now that we're automating the build, we won't be able to run unit tests against IE.

I've read Karma docs and I've learned about PhantomJS, but from what I read it is build on webkit which is chrome.

Searching the internet gave me no answer to my questions:
1. Is PhantomJS sufficient to cover IE, chrome and FF? because it seems the only straight forward solution I got from Karma.
2. Is there any way I can run karma unit tests on IE in a Linux box? it seems like a common requirement but I'm surprised I found no answer.

I've installed GNOME on the build box to try to get at least Chrome and FF covered, but the problem was that if I run the grunt build from a terminal (ie. Putty) it won't launch Chrome or FF, I have to log in from the GUI to be able to launch the browsers through Karma.

I've also tried to install wine to install IE on the build box, but it installed only IE6!! :)

Our team is relatively new to NodeJs and Angular, how would you setup your build box and how would you cover unit tests in IE??

Answer (score 1):

We ended up removing IE tests in Linux, but we run them in our windows dev boxes, and kept only Chrome and FF which are both working.